# How could a horizontal scrolling container have fixed elements attached?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am struggling trying to make a container behavior like a table of Apple Notes, for example. On the image below is possible to see blue squares attached to each row of content. As you can notice, the square is middle aligned according to row height.
[image]

When the container is scrolled, the blue squares keep visible on the same position. Only the row content is scrollable.
[image]

Important: the header is always visible, it is not scrolled.

Here is the code I am using to try achieve it:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 30rem;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.header {
  background: #D9D9D9;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.56rem 1.18rem;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.another-element {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  background: #529C9A;
}

.row {
  min-width: 60rem;
  padding: 1.56rem 1.18rem;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #D9D9D9;
}

.blue-square {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  background: #53A5D3;
  position: sticky;
  left: 1.25rem;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(calc(-1.25rem - 1.18rem))
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</strong>
    <div class="another-element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blue-square"></div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blue-square"></div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Euismod in sit tellus faucibus nec. Congue arcu in vel cum euismod vulputate. At nunc purus aliquam nunc curabitur turpis libero. Dolor tortor urna purus odio velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Euismod in sit tellus faucibus nec. Congue arcu in vel cum euismod vulputate. At nunc purus aliquam nunc curabitur turpis libero. Dolor tortor urna purus odio velit.
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blue-square"></div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blue-square"></div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without any code, but you can achieve this result with `position: sticky; left: 0;`.

Comment: @AmauryHanser thanks for your suggestion. I have improved the examples and added the code I am using. Hope it clarify what I am trying to achieve and the problems I am having.